# What is the meaning of bacon and not_bacon in the README of bcrypt.js?

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, bcryptjs

It's Part of the Code-Examples in the README-File.
"B4c0/\/" stands for 'password_example' I found out from another question here.

What means 'bacon' and 'not_bacon'?

````
    To check a password: 

```javascript
// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compareSync("B4c0/\/", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("not_bacon", hash); // false
```

Auto-gen a salt and hash:

```javascript
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('bacon', 8);
```
````

All I would like to know is, what these words stand for.

- "B4c0/\/"
- "bacon"
- "not_bacon"

I am just guessing and have no clue.

---

```
"B4c0/\/"    === the actual password from the database

"bacon"      === password input  

"not_bacon"  === wrong password input
```

Is my guess correct?

Comment: It is demonstrating the `compareSync` feature will resolve to true in the case that the string hashes to the same as the provided hash variable.  "B4c0/\/" resolves to the value of hash, returning a true boolean.  "not_bacon" does not resolve to the value of hash, and returns a false boolean.  The creation of the value of "hash" is shown here `var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('bacon', 8);`

Comment: You can use any word, like `whatever` and `not_whatever`; it's meant as a humorous example for the function, nothing more, nothing less.  (and now I want bacon )

Answer (score 1):

`B4c0/\/` is just an example of a password, such as one submitted by the user. `not_bacon` is an example of another user-submitted password. If `compareSync` returns true, then the password matches the hash. If `compareSync` returns false, then the password doesn't match the hash.

The particular strings chosen don't really matter. They only illustrate that a hash will only be validated against the password used to create the hash, and not against any old string.

Here, the hash was originally created by passing in `B4c0/\/` to bcrypt.

Later, when validating the user's input against the hash again, if they pass in `B4c0/\/` again, it will pass.

If they pass in something else that is not the hashed password, like `not_bacon`, it will fail.